# Can params[] be parameters for a lambda expression?

Tags: c#, lambda, closures, params-keyword

I've recently started exploring lambda expressions, and a question came to mind.  Say I have a function that requires an indeterminate number of parameters.  I would use the params keyword to model that variable number of parameters.

My question: can I do something similar with Lambda expressions?  For example:

```
Func<int[], int> foo = (params numbers[]) =>
                       {
                           int result;

                           foreach(int number in numbers)
                           {
                               result += numbers;
                           }

                           return result;
                       }
```

If so, two sub-questions present themselves - is there a 'good' way to write such an expression, and would I even want to write an expression like this at some point?

Comment: I wonder if you can actually call that a Lambda Expression, I think it is an Anonymous method.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich: It's a lambda. The => is the lambda operator.

Comment: @Andrew, I don't think that would work, but again I did not test it. Did you? Also, doing that is not really necessary, you can take a plain array `Func<int[], int> func = numbers => { /* ... */ }` and call the lambda with `func(new[] { 2, 3, 5, 7, 42 });`.

Comment: This code is untested, though I'm not _exactly_ worried about that;  I'm seeing if the concept of a lambda that uses a variable number of parameters is viable.  In my research through Microsoft's documentation, I found nothing.

Comment: @KendallFrey I found the exact definition, it is a Statement Lambda, not an Expression, which requires some specific rules that I think are broken inside those brackets.

Comment: @Yuriy, you're absolutely right, statement lambdas cannot be converted into expressions... but they're lambdas nonetheless :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, sort of.
First, instead of using `Func<>`, you would need to define a custom delegate:

```
public delegate int ParamsFunc (params int[] numbers);
```

Then, you could write a following lambda:

```
ParamsFunc sum = p => p.Sum();
```

And invoke it with variable number of arguments:

```
Console.WriteLine(sum(1, 2, 3));
Console.WriteLine(sum(1, 2, 3, 4));
Console.WriteLine(sum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
```

But to be honest, it is really much more straightforward to stick with built-in `Func<>` delegates.

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing that I think you can get would be something like this:

```
Func<int[], int> foo = numbers[] =>
                       {
                           // logic...
                       }

var result = foo(Params.Get(1, 5, 4, 4, 36, 321, 21, 2, 0, -4));
```

And have:

```
public static class Params
{
    public static T[] Get(params T[] arr)
    {
        return arr;
    }
}
```

But I can't see how that beats a simple `new[] {1, 5, 4, 4, ...}`

Answer (score 1):

There are two things here, the `Func<int[], int>` generic delegate on the LHS and the lambda expression on the RHS. The former is not possible, since a `Func<S, T>` delegate is declared like:

```
public delegate TResult Func<in T, out TResult>(T arg); //ie no params involved
```

You need your own delegate that accepts `params` input as shown in accepted answer.

The latter, which is what the question title is about, is not possible as well in C#, **but for a reason.**

The LHS of an assignment expression is a compile time thing (unless it's `dynamic` of course but again compiler is aware of it) and its RHS is a run time thing (unless of course in case of `const`s). The compiler can infer what's typed on LHS, but it gets the values on  RHS only during run time, ie when the code is run. When you type this:

```
Func<int[], int> foo = ....
```

`foo` is always considered as `Func<int[], int>`. It will add a lot of complexity to compiler if it had to decipher RHS. For e.g. if what you're attempting was possible, think about this scenario:

```
Func<int[], int> foo = (params int[] numbers) =>
                   {
                       int result;

                       foreach(int number in numbers)
                       {
                           result += numbers;
                       }

                       return result;
                   };

//and later at some other place
foo = (int[] numbers) => 0;

//how would you call 'foo' now?
```

*Instead when you write your own delegate that accepts `params`, you're telling the compiler directly (ie known from LHS)*.

Of the three features that parameters of a named method support, ie, `out/ref`, `params`, optional parameter, lambda expressions (or even the earlier `delegate` syntax) support only `out/ref`.